# How can I sort find output by printing the most 10 latest update files?

Tags: linux, find, ls, sort

on my linux machines I want to know which file/s are edited recently by users

let say I want to search recursive under `/home` the most 10 files that edited recently

**how to perform that with find command or other solution?**

example of expected output:

```
27/6/2018 11:23 /home/my_data/file
27/6/2018 10:21 /home/top/oo/pp/file
27/6/2018 09:23 /home/my_data/GG/file
```

Comment: ls -lrt will list in date order use man ls to look at ls options.

Comment: yes but I want to   search recursive

Comment: find with -mtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list recursively do

```
ls -lRrt
```

If you want to find all the files and list them in date change order

```
ls -lrt `find . -type f`
```

There's probably 10,000 ways to do it.

Comment: This won't scale if the find output generates so many filenames that you get "argument list too long". An `xargs` variant would help.

Answer (score 3):

Finding the newest 10 files under the current directory:

```
find -type f -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%TS\t%h/%f\n" | sort -r | head -n 10
```

Optionally add `| cut -f2` to strip the time information.

This uses to `-printf` option to `find` to print the modification time of the file in front of the filename separated by a tab, where the time is formatted in a way that can simply be sorted by `sort`. `sort -r` does reverse sorting to put the newest (i.e. "biggest") times at the beginning.

This falls down a bit with filenames that contain newlines. That can be worked around by ending the printf string not with `\n` but with `\0` to null-terminate the filenames. Then add `--zero-terminated` to the sort options, and put `| tr '\0' '\n'` at the end to convert the null bytes back into newlines.

Comment: What would I do if instead I want the final output to not contain the date information (but still be sorted by it)?